# How to send details stored in datagrid on server to client using SignalR Hub in winform

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

i have stored some client data on server in datagrid using signalr (whenever client connects details of all clients updated on server like ipaddress, name etc)... so i want to send that datagrid details to all clients and the condition is whenever new clients connect to server then all client including current client must get updated list ....here is my code basically what i have done till now,

```
  public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        object ipaddress;
        var a=Context.QueryString["name"];
        var b= Context.QueryString["AnotherValue"];
        if (Context.Request.Environment.TryGetValue("server.RemoteIpAddress", out ipaddress))
        {
            //ipcollections = new List<string[]>();

            userhandler.ipcol.Add(new string[] {  ipaddress.ToString(), a, b });
            Program.MainForm.writetodatagrid(userhandler.ipcol);
        }

        Program.MainForm.WriteToConsole("Client connected: " + Context.ConnectionId );
        return base.OnConnected();

    }
```

and showing this list on server itself in datagird...i have to send this list to all clients...please help me...thank you....or is there any other way or am i doing things wrong please tell me..

Comment: You can send messages to all clients from the server using `Clients.All`

Answer (score 0):

On the server you would have a Hub and a method on the Hub to broadcast.

```
    public class MyHub : Hub 
    { 
        public void Send(string ipaddress, string name) 
        { 
            Clients.All.addMessage(ipaddress, name); 
        }
    }
```

Take a look at the following post. It has a an example of what you would do on your winforms client.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b#content

and the source code for the winforms client:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b/sourcecode?fileId=119892&pathId=583880341